# MAX7219 led matrix prints unwanted artifacts when it is powered up

Tags: arduino, spi, arduino-uno, max7219

I’ve got Led matrix 32x8 which is driven by MAX7219. Like this:

[MAX7219 Dot Matrix Module Microcontroller 4 In One Display with 5P Line](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32597603008.html)

When I power it up, I can see different glitches.
How to power it up softly, without these glitches?

Answer (score 2):

What program are you using?

Possibly during startup (before initializing the signal pins), there are floating inputs.

Use either internal or hardware pulldown resistors to make sure 0 V is sent to all signal lines.

Comment: I am using arduino. Probably there is some noise on pins at first.How to suppress it?

Comment: By using pulldown resistors, they will force a pin/wire to go to GND level as long as there is no other signal on the line. E.g. try with one, find a pin of the MAX7219 that gives noise, add a e.g. 1 MOhm resistor from that pin to GND (and keep the jumper/wire to the Arduino as well).

Comment: what pins should I pull-down? There are CS, CLK and DIN.

Comment: Ah ok, you are using SPI … probably if you pull the DIN (data in) pin low it should be improved. However, it should not be necessary for SPI normally. You initialize SPI early in your program?

Comment: Actually, I don't use SPI. Pull-down resistor on DIN does no effect. I believe I need to find a way make be matrix be dark at initial powering up. Currently, when I plug it, it’s fully lightened.

Comment: Those pins seem to be SPI, so I'm a bit confused now how you control the MAX via your Arduino.

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry, you're right.

Comment: pull-down 10K on CS pin solved my problem

Comment: @zhekaus ok :-) Thanks for the notification

Comment: @zhekaus Did you only connected the CS pin directly to the GND pin with the 10K Ohm and also to the Arduino too? I am having similar problems so far (getting noise sometimes on the MAX display).

Comment: @PiMathCLanguage I did.